# How to outline only the border-radius when input is selected?

Tags: html, css, border, outline, radius

```css
.sear {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.sear:focus {
  //how to make only the border radius and other part of box selected?
}

.bar {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="display: inline; margin-left: 20%;" class="sear" placeholder="Search...">
<button class="bar">&#128270;</button>
```

I was just wondering if it is possible to select only the border-radius and the rest of the box when the mouse is focused on the input as opposed to the corner of the box.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML to your code, also the question is not clear, do you want to have `border-radius` only when input is focused?

Comment: Please add the HTML code that accompanies that so we can understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.Also your use of both "select" and "focus" are misleading, what kind of input is it

Comment: @ROOT and CypherJac just edited. I do not want the whole input text field to be selected  as I have border-radius. I only want the border-radius and the other part of the input text box to be selected.

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky, you mean to remove the outline?

Comment: "and the other part..." You need to be more specific.

Comment: @ROOT no I mean to make the outline surround the border including the border-radius

Comment: When you run the code snippet the corners of the left side are also outlined, how can i make the left side outline surround the border radius.

Comment: btw, your comment might be a problem with `//`. css comment is `/* css comment */`.

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky, you mean to have the outline `border-radius`? if thats the case, its not possible, [outline-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-outline-radius) its only supported by firefox and is not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the default outline (which is not recommended for accessibility reasons) and add your own you can do this by changing the border color on focus but I would recommend wrapping the elements with a div and using javascript to add and remove a class to make this styling change like this:

```js
var btnGroup = document.querySelector('.btn-group');
var input = document.querySelector('.sear');
input.onfocus = function() {
  btnGroup.classList.add('focus');
}
input.onblur = function() {
  btnGroup.classList.remove('focus');
}
```

```css
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
}
.btn-group.focus {
  border-color: rebeccapurple;
}
.sear {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: none;
}
.bar {
  padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  outline: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
.bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <input type="text" class="sear" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="bar">&#128270;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
.sear:focus {
    /* to change the border when selected. */
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have outline radius, its not posisble as mentioned in the comments, as a work around you can have something like this:

```css
.sear {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.sear:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #9ecaed;
}

.bar {
  display: inline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="display: inline; margin-left: 20%;" class="sear" placeholder="Search...">
<button class="bar">&#128270;</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to understand what you want.

May be something like this ?

```css
.sear {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.sear:focus {
  border-top: solid 3px blue;
  border-left: solid 3px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.sear:focus + .bar {
  border-top: solid 3px blue;
  border-right: solid 3px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 3px blue;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 54px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="sear" placeholder="Search..."/>
<button class="bar">&#128270;</button>
```